# Problems with init.d in a vagrant VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vagrant, init.d

I have written the following:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/bootForever
#

forever start /usr/local/src/mean/myapp/app.js
```

to the `/etc/init.d/bootForever`

I ran `sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/bootForever` followed by `sudo update-rc.d bootForever defaults` and the exitted the VM and ran `vagrant reload`. No joy.

SSHed back into the VM and ran `/etc/init.d/bootForever' directly in the command line, which had the effect I was after.

Why would this script not function during the VM boot, but work once booted? Is it an issue of timing? Can I ensure the script is ran at the very end?

VM Spec: `http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using absolute paths to the forever binary?

eg:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/bootForever
#

/usr/bin/forever start /usr/local/src/mean/myapp/app.js
```

Replace /usr/bin with where forever is located, which can usually be found by using the whereis or locate command.